# How exactly a child thread returns from its pthread_create()'s start function?

Tags: unix, operating-system, pthreads, solaris

I am currently taking the course of POSIX thread library using the Solaris operating system as an example and i got this question from my university teacher :

What exactly happens when a child thread meets on its way a return statement? (I answered that in this case an implicit call to pthread_exit is made, but my answer did not satisfy him, so he asked another one which is below).

What happens if this function is not this thread's start function, i.e. how does the OC khow on which return statement it is obliged to return control (to make an implicit call to pthread_exit) and on which not?

I guess I can paraphrase this as : "What exactly happens when a thread stumbles over a return statement?"

I don't know how to answer this question, so any help would be really appreciated!

P.S.

In fact when I looked through the assembly code of my program I could see that no implicit call to pthread_exit was made:

```
void* print_some_lines(void* args) {

    printf("Child printing..\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("Child's line number %d \n", i);
    }
    printf("Child done printing\n");
    return NULL;   
}
```

And

```
return NULL; 
}
```

equals

```
mov eax, 0   
leave
ret
```

in assembly

Comment: It's common for the OS to set up a new thread stack with the address of a stub function before the new thread jumps to the user-supplied start address of the thread function.  When/if the thread makes a top-level return, it executes the stub which contains a pthread_exit call.

Comment: @MartinJames Could you please elaborate more on these thread-related stubs? Or maybe you could recommend some literature where I could read this?

Comment: If the question is asked by your instructor, in the context of your class, then presumably they expect an answer drawn from, or at least based on, the lectures and / or course materials, if they expect an answer at all.  So what do those say?

Comment: In any event, the Pthreads specifications do not address the question, so it's an implementation issue.  How it's done on Solaris isn't necessarily how it's done on Linux, which isn't necessarily how it's done on other systems.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, the question is about how it's done on Solaris since I'm taking this course with Solaris operating system as an example. Our lectures do not say anything specific, they are just about the general idea. I guess it's student's responsibility to any find specific information. Since I couldn't find anything on this topic I thought someone could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly happens when a child thread meets on its way a return statement? (I answered that in this case an implicit call to pthread_exit is made, but my answer did not satisfy him, so he asked another one which is below).

As I wrote in comments, the Pthreads specification does not speak to the question, but after some consideration, I am inclined to say that the only plausible answers are all along the lines that the function returns control to its caller, just like any other time a `return` is executed.  My take, then, is that you are overthinking the question, and that's why you're having trouble finding an answer.

Note well that Pthreads does not distinguish "child threads" as a category -- once started, threads are all on equal ground.  Even the program's initial thread.  For example, any thread can join any other joinable thread, including the program's initial thread if that one happens to terminate by calling `pthread_exit()`.  Moreover, threads' start functions can be called directly, too, and they can be compiled separately from whatever function uses them with `pthread_create()`, so Pthreads cannot rely on there to be anything special about how they are compiled.

At the C language level, then, there's nothing special about thread start functions (unless you count their required prototype), nor about the functions they call.  All those functions have ordinary C semantics, including the ordinary semantics of the `return` statements they execute, as if the thread in which they run were the only thread in the program.  There are indeed special semantics invoked when the initial call to a thread's start function returns to its caller, but that's a responsibility of the Pthreads implementation, outside the scope of the C language.

I'd go so far as to opine that it is indeed a bit off to say even that a return from the initial call to a thread's start function implicitly calls `pthread_exit()`. Certainly the result observable by other threads is as if `pthread_exit(NULL)` were called, but it would be better to associate that with the Pthreads implementation itself than to imply that execution of the `return` statement has special, context-sensitive semantics.